# insert data in database with jqueryajax

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, sql-server

i have a form with c#(.net4) code behind . in this form user fill his specification and submit.
i wanna use ajax or post method in jquery for prevention of blink.i write flowing code. "success" function execute but it does not work and any record insert in database;i execute executemember method separately.it works without problem but it does not work with jquery ajax.where is problem?

```
[WebMethod]
    public static string executeinsert(string name ,string family , string username,string password , string  email,string tel, string codemeli)
    {   string constring = "data source=.;database=site;integrated security=true;";

        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constring);
        SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("insertmember", con);
        com.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        com.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@username", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 250));
        com.Parameters["@username"].Value = username;
        com.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@name", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 150));
        com.Parameters["@name"].Value = name;
        com.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@password", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50));
        com.Parameters["@password"].Value = password;
        com.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@family", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 250));
        com.Parameters["@family"].Value = family;
        com.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@email", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50));
        com.Parameters["@email"].Value = email;
        com.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@codemeli", SqlDbType.NChar, 10));
        com.Parameters["@codemeli"].Value = codemeli;
        com.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@tel", SqlDbType.NChar, 12));
        com.Parameters["@tel"].Value = tel;
        con.Open();
        com.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
        return "success";
        }
```

and its my jquery code

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(
    function () {
        $("#Button1").click(
            function () {
                var username, family, name, email, tel, codemeli, password;
                username = $('#<%=TextBox1.ClientID%>').val();
                name = $('#<%=TextBox2.ClientID%>').val();
                family = $('#<%=TextBox3.ClientID%>').val();
                password = $('#<%=TextBox4.ClientID%>').val();
                email = $('#<%=TextBox5.ClientID%>').val();
                tel = $('#<%=TextBox6.ClientID%>').val();
                codemeli = $('#<%=TextBox7.ClientID%>').val();

                $.ajax(
                {
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "WebApplication20.aspx/executeinsert",
                    data: "{'username':'username','name':name,
                            'family':family,'password':password,
                            'email':email,'tel':tel,
                            'codemeli':codemeli}",
                    contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",
                    async: true,
                    cache: false,
                    success: function(msg) {
                        alert(msg);
                    },
                    error: function (x, e) {
                        alert("The call to the server side failed. " 
                              + x.responseText);
                    }
                }
            );
        }
     )
 })
</script>
```

thank

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with the `data:"{'user...` line? Is it to pass a json string or a set of key/value pairs?

Comment: I'm not sure that it is the problem, but you pointed data type as JSON put provide string to the data attribute.

Comment: I see now it is an attempt at json, but it doesn't look like the WebMethod consumes json

Comment: Make sure your page method is being called and your json is correct. Please go through [this](http://encosia.com/using-jquery-to-directly-call-aspnet-ajax-page-methods/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this out:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#Button1").click(function () {
        var userData = new Object();

        userData.username = $('#<%=TextBox1.ClientID%>').val();
        userData.name = $('#<%=TextBox2.ClientID%>').val();
        userData.family = $('#<%=TextBox3.ClientID%>').val();
        userData.password = $('#<%=TextBox4.ClientID%>').val();
        userData.email = $('#<%=TextBox5.ClientID%>').val();
        userData.tel = $('#<%=TextBox6.ClientID%>').val();
        userData.codemeli = $('#<%=TextBox7.ClientID%>').val();

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "WebApplication20.aspx/executeinsert",
            data: userData,
            contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            async: true,
            cache: false,
            success: function (msg) {
                alert(msg);
            },
            error: function (x, e) {
                alert("The call to the server side failed. " + x.responseText);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

P.S. Try to debug and put breakpoint in the webmethod if it calls at all.

Comment: thank for reply .i do it .i put breakpoint and i find that webmethod dose not call .what is problem

Comment: Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6928533/calling-a-webmethod-with-jquery-in-asp-net-webforms

Answer (score 1):

I believe that your JSON doesn't have the correct format

Try validating your json [here](http://jsonlint.com).

You can see that your json is not valid.

Answer (score 0):

The `json` is not in right format  `'name':name` is not enclosed in the `'`, which are `string`.

```
data: "{'username' : 'username',   'name':name,'family':family,'password':password,'email':email,'tel':tel,'codemeli':codemeli    }",
```

it should be

```
   data: "{'username' : 'username', 'name':'name', 'family':'family', 'password':'password', 'email':'email', 'tel':'tel', 'codemeli':'codemeli'}",
```

Comment: I'm not sure, but even in the first case it should add record to DB with dummy data like: username, name, etc.. Is I understood no data were added at all. I can be mistaken.

Comment: you are right any record add to DB.i change data section but remain problem still. i forgot to say alert(msg) return null

Comment: Regarding the alert message as null, you need to return something.