# Call C# method from asp page .net

Tags: asp.net

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="textbox2" MaxLength="2" onfocus="textbox2_focus" />
```

and I have c# codebehind method:

`public void textbox2_focus(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var x = 5;
        }`

But This code tries to execute JavaScript Function.
How to execute c# function from code behind?
I tried something like:

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="textbox2" MaxLength="2" onfocus="<%=textbox2_focus() %>"/>
```

but didn't work.

Comment: I think you need to learn about the difference between client-side and server-side coding.  You're asking the browser to call a function on your server, which isn't going to work without a technology such as AJAX.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add below namespace

```
using System.Web.Services;
```

and define method like below

```
[WebMethod]
public void textbox2_focus(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ 
var x = 5; 
}
```

and call it from ajax

```
function textbox2_focus() {
       $.ajax({
               type: "POST",
               url: "pagename.aspx/textbox2_focus",
               data: '',
               contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
               dataType: "json",
               success: OnSuccess,
               failure: function (response) {
                // your code        
               }
             });
            }
    function OnSuccess(response) {

                  // your code
            }
```

Comment: But why sometimes It calls code behind method just with an attribute runat="server"?

Comment: If any server side event exists for that control then it calls server side event otherwise you do it as i specified

Answer (score 1):

try this

on textfocus call javascript function **call_textbox2_focus()** in this function click button

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="textbox2" MaxLength="2" onfocus="call_textbox2_focus()" />
<asp:Button ID="btnCallCodeBehind" Text="text" runat="server" style="display:none;" OnClick="textbox2_focus"/>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function call_textbox2_focus() {
        document.getElementById('<%= btnCallCodeBehind.ClientID %>').click();
    }
</script>
```

in code behind

```
    public void textbox2_focus(object sender, EventArgs e) { 

        var x = 5; 

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The `onfocus` event is a client-side event so you won't be able to directly access the server-side code.

You could run it through JavaScript and use an `XmlHttpRequest` or something similar to access a WebMethod written in C#.

Have a look at this answer: [Calling a webmethod with jquery in asp.net webforms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6928533/calling-a-webmethod-with-jquery-in-asp-net-webforms)