# How to be sure a JavaScript Method will be executed?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

to reduce the load of my page I start to exclude all heavy-load database-querys to WebMethods/Ajax, so have e.g. insted a siteload of 10 seconds a siteload of 0,5 seconds and a loading-screen of 9,5 seconds.

Here is an example:
Before:

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         //Do Heavy load query which takes long
    }
```

After:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

   function getOnlineList() {
        PageMethods.UpdateOnlineList(callbacksuccessOnline, callbackfail);
    }
  </script>
```

This works out well at the moment.
But I have the problem that in 1 of 10 loads of my site, the JavaScript doesn't find the Method, so I got an PageMethod "UpdateOnlineList" not found-error and nothing is loaded.
I expect this happens, when the Browser gets a hiccup and the PageMethods are not loaded right when JS trys to execute the query.

So, how to be safe das my JS is executed AFTER the methods are here?
I read much about JavaScript-PageLoad-Event or the Application Ready event, but don't know the exact difference AND which is the right for me!

Please help me :)

Comment: You should probably have a look at why it's failing 10% of the time as well?

Comment: How does `UpdateOnlineList` get added to `PageMethods`? I assume you're the one who does it? In this case it really should work without any timeouts and waiting queues and stuff like that. You just have to make sure that your code runs in the order in which you want it to run. Maybe the only thing you need is to put the part in which you actually call a function inside of a document.ready event handler, i.e. `document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () { .... }, false)`.

Comment: basilikum It's not specified in the question, but from the usage of PageMethods, I'm assuming that he's using the ASP.Net AJAX ScriptManager, that generates that javascript automatically.

Answer (score 0):

just check if the method exists or not before firing

```
checkIfExists();

function checkIfExists()
{
    if ( PageMethods.UpdateOnlineList )
    {
       PageMethods.UpdateOnlineList(callbacksuccessOnline, callbackfail);
    }
    else
    {
       setTimout( checkIfExists , 1000 );
    }
}
```

Comment: Isn't usefull... I wished that Method to execute 100%, not to avoid an error.

Comment: @Kovu In that case, set the timeout in the if condition and check after sometime. updated the code

Comment: I could do that, but for 50 methods in my site its a very lonmg sotry, I thing there is an entry point for that...

Comment: @Kovu you can generalize the same by passing the method reference as well as success and error callback method references

Answer (score 0):

You could try using the page methods without ScriptManager, and using jQuery instead. This way you could also use the jQuery ready event.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $.get( "PageName.aspx/UpdateOnlineList", callbacksuccessOnline)
   .fail(callbackfail);
});
```

There's more information on this thread, but it's a bit outdated:
[Calling a webmethod with jquery in asp.net webforms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6928533/calling-a-webmethod-with-jquery-in-asp-net-webforms)