# Unable to access webmethod on aspx.cs page

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, webforms, webmethod

I am trying to call a webmethod with jquery ajax. However, the call returns a Not Found error. Trying to access the method directly via the URL also returns a 404 error.

I made sure to add `EnablePageMethods="true"` parameter to the `<asp:ToolkitScriptManager>` on the master page.

**Announcements.aspx**:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("#CreateBtn").click(function () {
            var announce = {};
            announce["title"] = "An Announcement";
            announce["body"] = "Announcement Body";

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "Announcements.aspx/AddAnnouncement",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                data: JSON.stringify(announce),
                success: function () {
                    alert("success!");
                },
                error: function (x, t, e) {
                    alert(t); //alerts "error"
                    alert(e); //alerts "Not Found"
                }
            });
            return false;
        })
    });
</script>
```

**Announcements.aspx.cs**

```
using System.Web.Services;

namespace MyProject.ContentTools
{   
public partial class Announcements : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }

    [WebMethod]
    public static string AddAnnouncement(string title, string body)
    {
        var newTitle = title;
        var newBody = body;

        return "it worked!";
    }
}
}
```

Comment: I think you are missing WebMethod parenthesis (WebMethod())

Comment: Did you try using the full path in the URL param?

Comment: This is a resting service right?  If so try [WebGet(UriTemplate = "Announcements.aspx/AddAnnouncement/{args=null}")] in place of WebMethod

Comment: @Viru - No it's not required, `WebMethod` is not a method it is an attribute.

Comment: @W3AVE: Just tried it. Doesn't help.

Comment: Does the call work when you switch method to Get?

Comment: I just realized its a post, saw a return and got confused.  In that case you can try [WebInvoke](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.web.webinvokeattribute(v=vs.110).aspx).    So it would like [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", UriTemplate = "Announcements.aspx/AddAnnouncement")]

Comment: One the line above [WebMethod] try adding [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptMethod()]

Comment: @dtucker1914: Tried it. Doesn't help.

Comment: Just for curiosity, try removing second parameter, so that you have only text sent to the web method, and see if that works

Comment: One more thing - do you use any kind of url rewriting? If yes, that might be another problem

Comment: You could try to get it working without any input parameters as in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6928533/calling-a-webmethod-with-jquery-in-asp-net-webforms to make sure the call (url, etc) itself is actually OK.

Comment: @RahulSingh I do know WebMethod is not method but a attribute...parenthesis in attributes is used to provide positional or named parameters..Anyway, OP has confirmed it does not work....

Comment: Your web method looks correct. can you show the ASPX code for the element with id `CreateBtn` ? May  be the ajax code is not getting called because if you don't have `ClientIdMode='static'` in div element then the id will be prefixed with some other string then the click will not work.

Comment: did you figure this out yet?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using PageMethods from within an ASP.NET **MVC** project, you probably need to ignore the routes for aspx pages (and, therefore, the PageMethod urls that are based on them). In your route registration (usually at `App_Start/RouteConfig.cs`), add the following line:

```
routes.Ignore("{*allaspx}", new { allaspx = @".*\.aspx(/.*)?" });
```

This should allow the PageMethod request to go through without interference from MVC routing.

Answer (score 0):

i'm not sure about the 404 problem exactly, but a couple other things:

- you're using `<asp:ToolkitScriptManager>`. this should be a `<asp:ScriptManager>` (makes a difference??);
- if using jquery's ajax, i think the `<asp:ScriptManager>` is not even required;

Answer (score 0):

Try this..You have to add ScriptMethod notation in your method...

```
[WebMethod]    
 [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]  
        public static string AddAnnouncement(string title, string body)
        {
            var newTitle = title;
            var newBody = body;

            return "it worked!";
        }
and in your ajax method try to change data format.

    $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "Announcements.aspx/AddAnnouncement",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",
                    data: JSON.stringify(title: announce.title, body: announce.body),
                    success: function () {
                        alert("success!");
                    },
                    error: function (x, t, e) {
                        alert(t); //alerts "error"
                        alert(e); //alerts "Not Found"
                    }
                });
```

Answer (score -2):

Try this..You have to call PageMethods like below in your jquery..

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("#CreateBtn").click(function () {

            var title = "An Announcement";
            var body = "Announcement Body";
             PageMethods.AddAnnouncement(title,body,success,error);
        function success(result) {
                    alert("success!");
                }
        function error(result) {
                    alert(result); 
                }
            });
            return false;
        })
    });
</script>
```