# AJAX call not working in ASP.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-web-api

I have problem while using **AJAX** in **ASP.Net**.getName not fired.. anything wrong.? Please find the below samples and suggest me.

```
 ` <input type="button" value="Bulk Save" id="savebtn" />`

$("#savebtn").click(function () {
            var firstName = "SAmple";
            var lastName = "Name";
            var param = { fs: firstName, ls: lastName };
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: '<%=ResolveUrl("~/Features.aspx/getName")%>',
                data:JSON.stringify(param),
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                //async:true
            })
        });

    [WebMethod]
    public static void getName(string fs, string ls)
    {

    }
```

Comment: Have you tried add [HttpPost] above your getname() method?

Comment: What error do you get in the browser console?

Comment: @IkramTurgunbaev That's not necessary. That would be for MVC or Web API, but this is Web Forms's WebMethods. Different.

Comment: Check here: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6928533/calling-a-webmethod-with-jquery-in-asp-net-webforms](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6928533/calling-a-webmethod-with-jquery-in-asp-net-webforms)

Comment: Check here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6928533/calling-a-webmethod-with-jquery-in-asp-net-webforms

Comment: Have you tried this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6928533/calling-a-webmethod-with-jquery-in-asp-net-webforms

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are using a separate js file for your ajax code, then you can use this

`url:'http://domain_name/controller_name/method'`

otherwise

```
url: "Features.aspx/getName"
```

Comment: Could you also explain why?  Thanks!

Comment: Since it will look in root directory, it is an absolute path and it will be effective...i have tried this and it is working fine. Thank you!